# The correct step in setting up a Wordpress block tutorial?

Tags: wordpress

While I do have experience working in WP and creating WP themes. I am new to learning about blocks. Therefore, someone gave a link to learn about blocks: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/. However, I thought I should start with the prerequisites in which I can set up development environment and a new wordpress site, which is at: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/devenv/.

However, I got stuck after the step "install npm -g install @wordpress/env" It said after this: "Start the environment from an existing plugin or theme directory, or a new working directory:" I thought I was missing something so I tried to look around online if someone followed the Block tutorial and wrote about what they did. I also came across https://davidyeiser.com/tutorials/docker-wordpress-theme-setup that should help me set up a new environment and new Wordpress site with Docker.

Is this the correct way I should be going before I download the "https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples" to work with as I go through the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the right or wrong way to start learning developing blocks for Gutenberg. Personally I started in a similar way as you are talking about. I just did the [beginners tutorial](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/create-block/), and after I understood how that was connected I modified that plugin to my taste. Since then I've just been using that plugin and workflow for every project I have. It's worth mentioning that I had some experience with [React](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gZD-Tvwfod2gaISzfRiP9d) before I started working with this which came in really handy to understand the system.

After that **I would recommend** looking into [wp-bg.com](https://wp-gb.com/) for a better visualization, examples and snippets of the different components that Gutenberg offers. The documentation that WordPress themselves provides on Gutenberg is a bit limited regarding the different components and tools that comes with Gutenberg.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm clear in my asking if "https://davidyeiser.com/tutorials/docker-wordpress-theme-setup" is the correct step to take after the step "install npm -g install @wordpress/env". Is the article about docker and wordpress setup the correct step to take next before I download the examples to work with as I go through the tutorial.